# Tracking a particular ports on my server

Tags: security, nmap

on my apache server,want to track a particular port through my local pc at home so how is it possible with nmap ,suppose the port number is 3080.
any commands?

Comment: What do you mean by 'track' it?

Comment: track it means,any kind of activity like downloading or uploading etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the `tcpdump` command:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -n -i eth2 dst port 3080
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth2, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
```

This listening on the `eth2` interface (my wireless connection) for outgoing connections to port 3080.

And in another shell:

```
$ telnet google.com 3080
```

To see the connection attempt:

```
16:52:38.073965 IP 192.168.1.10.51290 > 74.125.227.70.3080: Flags [S], seq 4004145863, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 38502 ecr 0,nop,wscale 4], length 0
16:52:39.071494 IP 192.168.1.10.51290 > 74.125.227.70.3080: Flags [S], seq 4004145863, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 38752 ecr 0,nop,wscale 4], length 0
16:52:41.075491 IP 192.168.1.10.51290 > 74.125.227.70.3080: Flags [S], seq 4004145863, win 14600, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 39253 ecr 0,nop,wscale 4], length 0
^C
3 packets captured
3 packets received by filter
0 packets dropped by kernel
```

See also [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/)